# Best way to call external web API from php

Tags: php, asynchronous, redis, queue, rabbitmq

What is the best way to call external web API from php script so that user does not have to wait for long running task to complete (for example, fetching data from some website when it is slow or unresponsive)?

Answer (score 0):

Typically [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is your best bet for external API's

However, if you are worried about the user's wait time then don't use PHP at all.

PHP is server-side, meaning the user won't see anything until the server is done processing the document. The best practice is to let the page load with a "please wait" message and then use JavaScript to access the API.